# Send URL Message as Parameters

Tags: struts2

In servlets I used

```
  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?msg=Login failed");
```

msg after ? to send message while redirecting.
How to do same things with struts2

Since redirection is via struts.xml

```
 <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
```

I am just a beginner in struts framework

Comment: The result you show is not a redirect, it is a forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your action class which extends `ActionSupport`:

```
addActionError("Login failed");
```

in your index.jsp:

```
<s:actionerror/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<result name="error" type="redirect" >
  <param name="location">index.jsp?msg=${actionMessage}</param>
  <param name="parse">true</param>
  <param name="encode">true</param>
</result>
```